# Admob allows to place more than one ads in an activity?

Tags: admob

After reviewing the admob policies, I haven't seen the max ads unit in an activity anymore. So does they allow to place more than one ads in an activity now ?

Comment: there is restriction on how many interstitial ads you can place simultaneously. However I also didn't find any restriction on showing banner  within same activity. However if you place multiple banners within in same activity,  you will not follow guidelines provided here resulting in ban of your application (https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6275345?hl=en&ref_topic=2745287)

Answer (score 0):

You've been downvoted into oblivion, but just to answer your question: AdMob's policy is that **you can only have one ad visible at a time**.

It's technically possible for you to have two banners in one activity and never show them at the same time, but it's almost always better to just have the one.